How to setup SPF record with Hover/Digital Ocean?
I'm trying to setup SPF record and I followed some tutorials but I'm a bit confused. My email and website domain is hosted on Hover and the files of my website are hosted on Digital Ocean. My domain name is pointed to ns1.digitalocean.com | ns2.digitalocean.com | ns3.digitalocean.com.
First, I don't know where to configure the SPF record, on Hover or on Digital Ocean?
Also, in this syntax v=spf1 include:_spf.hostedemail.com ~all what hostedemail.com is supposed to be?
Here are some tutorial I read:

https://support.hover.com/support/solutions/articles/201000064663-creating-an-spf-record
https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/14707808393499-DigitalOcean-DNS-Setup-Guide#01GYD50BBNX6HCW2ENZTEG4S94 (I'm not using Mailgun, my webmail is hosted on Hover).

But I don't know where and what to put exactly in my case.

You add the record in the DNS settings at Digital Ocean.  Per my comment on Superuser.com the syntax should be exactly as in your question - "v=spf1 include:_spf.hostedemail.com ~all"  - hostedemail.com is the correct reference for Hover's email server.

Thanks! I did it and it works!
